# PostgresSql instal user cannot login?

Tags: postgresql, authentication

I'm new to PostgresSql (version 11), and want to connect to it (perform createdb.exe etc).
However, the Windows logged on user "me" is asked for a password, I used my windows password, my installer password and the password for a super user of the database but none of them work. 
What can this be ?.

Comment: Have you tried an empty password? By default the postgres database uses postgres as user and accepts empty password

Comment: What installer did you use? The one by EnterpriseDB?

Answer (score 1):

> my installer password and the password for a super user of the database

Aren't those the same thing?  How did the super user password get set, if not from the installer?

Did you try to login as the superuser's PostgreSQL account?  `psql -U postgres -h 127.0.0.1`, for example.  You can't use a super user's password to login as a different user, like "me" (not even if "me" is also a superuser).

Comment: Yes i used the installer a few times in the end kept all passwords the same but no luck. so "psql -U me -h 127.0.0.1 "doesnt work for me